# Uniform Lipschitz function approximation by shallow neural networks

Tags: reference-request, approximation-theory, machine-learning

Fix $d\in \mathbb{N}$. Let $F_1$ be the set of all 1-Lipschitz functions mapping $[0, 1]^d$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

For $\varphi: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $m \in \mathbb{N}$, let $N_\varphi^m$ be the set of feed-forward neural network functions with input dimension $d$, output dimension 1, hidden dimension m, two layers and activation function $\varphi$. That means $N_\varphi^m$ is the set of functions $h: \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $h(x) = b_0 + \sum_{i=1}^m b_i \varphi(a_0 + \sum_{j=1}^d a_j x_j)$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$, where $a_0, ..., a_d \in \mathbb{R}$ and $b_0, ..., b_m \in \mathbb{R}$ are the weights of the network.

I am looking for the following result, which I expect to exist somewhere in the literature (for a suitable activation function $\varphi$):

**Does the following hold?**

For any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists some $m \in \mathbb{N}$, such that for any $f \in F_1$ there exists $f^m \in N_\varphi^m$ so that for all $x \in [0, 1]^d$ it holds $|f(x)-f^m(x)|<\varepsilon$.

More abstractly, I am looking for a standard universal approximation result for neural networks, but the necessary hidden dimension $m$ should only depend on the function class (Lipschitz functions), not on the specific function.

In [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.01145.pdf) paper the authors achieve this kind of result (Theorem 1), but they require deep neural networks instead of shallow ones.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can check Theorem 4 in Poggio et al. "Why and When Can Deep-but Not Shallow-Networks Avoid the Curse of Dimensionality: A Review"

Comment: Thanks, this indeed looks like the kind of result I need. However, I'll leave the check mark open for now, as there might be results out there with a more direct proof or more general activation functions!